# What is the way to better organize the data charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mui-x-charts

I am using React (mui/x-charts) and I have this problem
[As you see the Brands are not very well stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OZGZ.png)

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
                {datasGraphBar != undefined ? datasGraphBar.map((graph, index) => (
                    <Grid xs={12} md={6} key={index} className={'text-center'}>
                        <Typography variant="h6">
                            {graph.title}
                        </Typography>
                        <div className={'text-center'}>
                            <BarChart
                                xAxis={[{data: xAxis, scaleType: 'band'}]}
                                series={graph.datas}
                                width={700}
                                height={300}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Grid>
                )) : ''}
                {datasGraphLines != undefined ? datasGraphLines.map((graph, index) => (
                    <Grid xs={12} md={6} key={index} className={'text-center'}>
                        <Typography variant="h6">
                            {graph.title}
                        </Typography>
                        <div className={'text-center'}>
                            <LineChart
                                xAxis={[{data: xAxis, scaleType: 'point'}]}
                                series={graph.datas}
                                width={700}
                                height={300}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Grid>
                )) : ''}
            </Grid>
```

This is my code, can someone help me?
I was trying to find the fix in docs but can't find it

I tried to find the documentation on how to change this but I am unable to find

Comment: Which library have you used to render charts ?

Comment: @SrushtiShah mui/x-charts

Comment: Have you tried applying css ?

Comment: @makic try this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-farrell-hr2mq2)

Comment: @SrushtiShah No I did not. I thought there is a more proper way of doing it

Comment: @DoubleH Thanks, I will try that

Comment: @DoubleH Its working perfectly, thanks! Can you give me maybe a link where can I find the info on how you did this? Like where in docs you saw that you could do this?

Comment: https://mui.com/x/react-charts/legend/